# How do I paste into the Windows CMD prompt by using only the keyboard?

Tags: windows, command-line

My current technique is to right-click in the command prompt and then click paste.  This bugs me - is there a better way?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does anyone know why they didn't just add support for a control-v paste command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its not amazingly user friendly, but you can paste with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>p</kbd>.

From [here](http://blog.jozjan.net/2008/06/howto-paste-clipboard-contents-to.html).

Answer (score 6):

This was solved on [Server Fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131955/keyboard-shortcut-to-paste-clipboard-content-into-command-promt-window-win-xp):

> I personally use a little [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script to remap certain keyboard functions, for the console window (CMD) I use:>
>
> ```
> ; Redefine only when the active window is a console window 
> #IfWinActive ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass> 
>
> ; Close Command Window with Ctrl+w
> $^w::
> WinGetTitle sTitle
> If (InStr(sTitle, "-")=0) { 
>     Send EXIT{Enter}
> } else {
>     Send ^w
> }
>
> return 
>
>
> ; Ctrl+up / Down to scroll command window back and forward
> ^Up::
> Send {WheelUp}
> return
>
> ^Down::
> Send {WheelDown}
> return
>
>
> ; Paste in command window
> ^V::
> ; Spanish menu (Editar->Pegar, I suppose English version is the same, Edit->Paste)
> Send !{Space}ep
> return
>
> #IfWinActive
> ```

Answer (score 4):

alt+space+E+P should do it

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10, you [can enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>V</kbd> to work in the command prompt](http://www.howtogeek.com/197749/how-to-power-up-the-windows-10-command-prompt-with-ctrlc-and-ctrlv/):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your screenshots are incorrect, you don't seem to be in windows 10, it seems to be windows 8/8.1.

Comment: @WasifHasan same location on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Control and V, like the rest of the OS :P

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
^v:: Send !{Space}ep
#IfWinActive
```

(Yep, that's just automating the previous answers, but automating them it is. Autohotkey! :))