# How to paste to cmd.exe without a mouse?

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I paste into the Windows CMD prompt by using only the keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/62598/how-do-i-paste-into-the-windows-cmd-prompt-by-using-only-the-keyboard)

The usual way to paste text in a cmd.exe shell is to right-click.  How can you paste text using only the keyboard?

Comment: Possible Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/62598/how-do-i-paste-into-the-windows-cmd-prompt-by-using-only-the-keyboard

Comment: @mehper Nice find!

Comment: On Windows 10, you can enable Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V in cmd.exe, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31506358/395857

Answer (score 19, accepted):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> :

> <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for System Menu
>   <kbd>E</kbd> for Edit sub-menu
>   <kbd>P</kbd> for Paste item

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't a more direct way, without going through the system menu, but I'm sure you are right.

Comment: yup that's how i do it.

Answer (score 10):

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
^v:: ;Paste in console
send !{Space}EP
return
#ifWinActive
```

in AutoHotKey, allowing you to Control+V to paste :)

With AutoIt you can also fix the ALT-F4 on your command prompt.
Combined the script will be:

```
#Include <HotKey.au3>
#Include <vkConstants.au3>
; Assign "CTRL-V" to PasteDos()
_HotKeyAssign(BitOR($CK_CONTROL, $VK_V), 'PasteDos', -1, "[CLASS:ConsoleWindowClass]")
; Assign "ALT-F4" to ExitDoc()
_HotKeyAssign(BitOR($CK_ALT, $VK_F4), 'ExitDos', -1, "[CLASS:ConsoleWindowClass]")

; Make sure we don't exit
While 1
    Sleep(10)
WEnd
Func PasteDos()
   Send(ClipGet ( ))
EndFunc

Func ExitDos()
   WinClose("[ACTIVE]", "")
EndFunc
```

To get this running install   [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/), add the [Hotkey include](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/90492-hotkey-au3/), save the above script with au3 extension and run it.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 8):

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131955/keyboard-shortcut-to-paste-clipboard-content-into-command-prompt-window-win-xp). The short (but unpleasant answer) is:

> <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <-- for copy and
>   <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> <-- for paste.

Comment: +1 for "short but unpleasant answer."  And thanks for the link to the further explanation on StackOverflow.

Comment: No problem. If you stop by SO, upvote the answers there since they're really good :)

Answer (score 6):

In addition to these answers, it might be noted that in cmd.exe you have to enable quick-edit mode in order for <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, <kbd>p</kbd> to work. Quick-edit mode can be enabled by clicking on the top left corner in cmd.exe, then selecting **properties**, then going to the **options** tab.