# Pasting into the command line

Tags: windows, svn, command-line, productivity, cvs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I paste into the Windows CMD prompt by using only the keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/62598/how-do-i-paste-into-the-windows-cmd-prompt-by-using-only-the-keyboard)

I'd like to be able to paste commands right into the command line prompt in windows.

Sounds trivial but it isn't working (ctrl+V doesn't work) and it would increase my productivity a lot when I'm following let's say a process as described in a manual. Should be a way to do it though.

Comment: @lok: http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/ is a different option if you can't get cmd.exe to behave how you want

Comment: exact duplicate of [How do I paste into the Windows CMD prompt by using only the keyboard?](http://superuser.com/questions/62598/how-do-i-paste-into-the-windows-cmd-prompt-by-using-only-the-keyboard)

Answer (score 5):

Not a programming question, but you can just right click the app icon, select "Properties", and turn on quick edit mode.  Right click now pastes.

Now voting to move to SuperUser...

Comment: +1 for QuickEdit.  QuickEdit is the first thing I turn on at the command prompt.  Make sure you say "change for all windows from this shortcut" or whatever the terminology is, so that you'll always be in quickedit mode.

Answer (score 2):

It is unfortunate that ctrl+v doesn't work, but right click and paste isn't too bad of an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

(... This applies to XP, and basically works in later Windows, but they may offer more).
The Windows console does have **Copy** // **Paste** // **Find** available.
However it is not handled in the normaal GUI way.. ie. Ctrl+C/P/F do not work.

You can use the keyboard or mouse to Copy.

**Copy** selects text in a rectangular **block**  (*not* on a wrapped-line basis).

**Keyboard Copy**:
 **Alt+Space** (to activate the System-menu), then use the **Up/Down/Left/Right** to navigate, and then in conjuntion with `Shift` to select the **block** of text.
Once you have selected the **block**, you must press `Enter` to finalize the **copy** command (this `Enter` is not passed to the command-line (some text must be selected, of course).

**Keyboard Paste**:
 **Alt+Space** (to activate the System-menu), then **E** (`Edit`), then **P** (`Paste`)

**Mouse **Copy**:
 Turn on `Quick Edit` (**Alt+Space**, then **P**).. nb. Copy is only available in block-mode.

**Mouse Paste**:  Only via the Console's System-menu (but I think this is not shown in Vista.. (7? may be the same)... just use the keyboard method... Its a quick as a wink, once you become familiar with it.

For **Find**, just follow suit.